# Characterise distribution overlap

Tags: distributions, autoencoders, overlapping-data

I'm applying VAEs to sections genomic data (haplotypic vcf format, so binary variables), with one model being trained on each section. Depending on which section I'm applying these methods to, my models sometimes exhibit mode searching behaviour quite heavily.

[image: PCA plots showing data before and after autoencoding]

These are PCA plots of my data for 4 sections before and after autoencoding. In the two plots on the left, the decoded data quite visibly concentrates in the densest regions of the distribution of the base data, with a "path" of samples between these modes. On the right, the decoded data is much more dispersed throughout the distribution of the base data.

Is there some form of metric I can use to quantify how well the distriubtion of decoded data overlaps with the distriubtion of the base data? Should I just calculate average distance from original to decoded, or is there something that could be used at the scale of the distribution directly?